# iPad mini as device in xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode6

I'm developing my first App and I'm testing it in my iPhone 5c, but when I connect my iPad Mini it displays some error and something related to my "Member center" in the apple website.

My question is: I have to purchase another license to run my iPad mini with xcode? Because I have already a license and I don't know why is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Given that your device iOS is the same or newer than the deployment target of your Xcode project, you just need to add the UDID to your Apple Developer account, renew the Development certificate (and Provisioning Profile if necessary) and enable Development mode of the device in Xcode, then you can use the new device for development.

Comment: Thanks Raptor, I'm going to try with that. Regards.